# Access to properties of an object Func<S, T>

Tags: c#

I do not know the full operation of `Func<T, TResult>`, so maybe my question is simple or obvious to some of you.

I have the following header of a function:

```
private static T MyMethod<S, T>(Func<S, T> testFunc) where S : class, new()
{
   //Code....
}
```

I want to access to the properties from `S` object. Possible?

For example: `S.name`

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can't you use an interface for `S`? Then you would do `where S : IMyInterface`. If you do this, you'll be able to access `S` properties defined on `IMyInterface`

Comment: @Claudio Redi In case you do not use an interface, it is not possible? is that if I use the interface, the method would stay coupled and just is not what I want: (

Comment: It sounds like you want to access any object of type `S` from inside `MyMethod` that would be put into `testFunc` (from any other place). That is (as far as I know) not possible and not how [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549151.aspx) is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that in your method, you don't *have* an `S` object. You have a function that takes an `S` and returns a `T`. In this case, I would assume that *your method* is responsible for making the `S` instances and passing them to `testFunc` as parameters.

However, it is possible for you to get access to the type information of `S`, using reflection:

```
private static T MyMethod<S, T>(Func<S, T> testFunc) where S : class, new()
{
   var typeofS = typeof(S);

   var s = new S();
   var defaultName = (string)(typeofS.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(s, null));
}
```

(I hope its obvious but, if you get an `S` that doesn't have a `Name` property, the reflection will fail; production code should of course be doing a lot more `null` checking, exception handling, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you write:

```
private static T MyMethod<S, T>(Func<S, T> testFunc) where S : S, new()
{
   //Code....
}
```

With S who are you class type ? Or your abstract class type where you already have some common properties ?

Comment: S is a Object, but not have base class, the object have different properties, and I need access to all... I explain me?

Comment: It will always be the same class ? If yes you can replace your code by this:

`private static T MyMethod<YourClassName, T>(Func<YourClassName, T> etstFunc)`

Comment: I want to avoid coupling method ... I have it in another project... tnks

Comment: You can have an common abstract class who will share the same property between your differents children class. If you want to use them in the content of you methods... And a cast/reflexion isn't an appropriate solution. (It will works, but it isn't the better...)

Answer (score 0):

All your method knows about an `S` is that it's a class and can be instantiated. It does not know if it has a property called `name`. You may need to require that parameter to inherit from an interface or class that has the expected properties.

You could also try casting to a know type, understanding that the cast may fail if the object is not of that type.